# Qiskit: count the type of gates on the qubit with the largest number of gates in a multi-qubit circuit

Tags: programming, qiskit

I would like to know the number and type of all the gates on the wire/qubit with the largest operations in a quantum circuit with multiple qubits. Is there any inbuilt functionality, or what is the shortest way to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this as follow:

1. Specify your circuit then transpile it to the backend of interst.

> `transpile_circuit = transpile(circuit, backend)`

2. Convert this to DAG (Directed Acylic Graph)

> `dag_circuit = circuit_to_dag(transpile_circuit)`

3. count all the operation in the longest path:

> `dag_circuit.count_ops_longest_path()`

---

***Explicit example:***

Says you have the circuit

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(4,4)
for i in range(4):
    qc.h(i)
qc.cx(0,1)
qc.cx(2,3)
qc.ry(2,0)
qc.cx(1,0)
qc.measure([0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3])
```

[image]

you can transpile this onto `ibmq_16_melbourne` and to get:

```
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne')
transpile_circuit = transpile(qc, backend)
```

[image]

Now, convert to DAG and counts ops give you:

```
dag_circuit = circuit_to_dag(transpile_circuit)
dag_circuit.count_ops_longest_path()
```

Output: `{'rz': 4, 'sx': 3, 'cx': 2, 'measure': 1}`

---

It seems to me you want to find out the runtime of the circuit by finding out the longest path, and the operations on that path, then using the device properties to calculate the theoretical runtime.

If that is the case, then you need to extract the gate duration time for all the gate in that longest path, and work out the calculation.

---

Make sure to import:

```
from qiskit.dagcircuit import DAGCircuit
from qiskit.converters import circuit_to_dag
from qiskit.compiler import transpile
```

Comment: You caught me on my heels: yes, I wanted the theoretical runtime! Note however that the circuit with the longest path need not have the longest runtime, since single and two-qubit gates have orders of magnitude of difference in their execution times :)

Answer (score 0):

Your description sounds like the notion of *depth*. You can get the depth of a circuit in Qiskit with the `depth` method: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.depth

```
circuit.depth()
```

Comment: note that `depth` is just the longest path length. It does not return the operations within the path.

Comment: Yeap. You answer is more complete.