# Issues in calculating exact runtime on ibmq_16_melbourne

Tags: programming, qiskit

I am working on calculating the exact runtime of a quantum circuit on the `ibmq_16_melbourne` device. I am using the API `result.time_taken` to calculate the run time.

```
result = execute(circuit, backend, shots=8000).result()
counts = result.get_counts(circuit)
print(counts)
print("Time taken: ", result.time_taken)
```

I executed by python code on ibm quantum lab (which is a Jupyter notebook) and also using Pycharm on my laptop. I get huge variations in the results. So, I concluded that `result.time_taken` does not provide the run time correctly. I am going through the documentation, but still could not find the solution.

Please provide some solution to calculate exact runtime.

Comment: Do you know if `time_taken` considers the queue time? If so, that probably makes up for the variations you are seeing.

Comment: No, time_taken doesnot include the queue time.

Comment: See this: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/17768/9858

Comment: Hi @KAJ226, I am trying to find the exact time taken in execution of the circuit inside the quantum computer. Your solution is different.

Comment: @ManuChaudhary ok. You can do this theoretically. This might help: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/17304/9858  You can at least write a function that approximate the time your circuit takes per shot... then multiply that by however number of shots you used. If you use more than 8192 shots then you have to load another circuit, which has an overhead of about 15 seconds.

Comment: Hi @KAJ226, do we need to calculate the time delay for the "measure" also? Also, the time delay for Rz comes out to be zero( little difficult to understand).  Also, if have to calculate the running time on Qasm Simulator, is there any similar API for the Qasm Simulator also? Thank you for this great help.

Comment: The measurement steps are the most expensive so you want to take that into account. The gate with the longest time is the CX gate... which ranges from 400 ns to 1000 ns. The RZ gate, which equivalent to U1 gate https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.U1Gate.html within an overall phase factor, is performed using a frame change so it is essentially free. See his paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.00858.pdf