# Qiskit: Count of each gates

Tags: qiskit

I wanted to calculate the count of each gate used in the specific quantum circuit. For example in the below circuit, the result should be something like:

```
{'rz': 1, 'h': 4, 'cx': 3, 'measure': 4}
```

I saw a [similar](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17301/qiskit-count-the-type-of-gates-on-the-qubit-with-the-largest-number-of-gates-in) question asked, but it counts all the gates only in the longest path of the dag circuit which it creates using `circuit_to_dag`.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use QuantumCircuit's [`count_ops()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.count_ops.html) method:

```
print(dict(circ.count_ops()))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `QuantumCircuit.count_ops()` method. The documentation for it can be found here: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.count_ops.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.count_ops it returns a dictionary of the number of each particular operation in the circuit.

Comment: Thank you. It worked.